# WSO2 ESB - XML to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, xml, wso2, esb

I need a solution for a problem:
I just tried this example for the WSO2 ESB and it is working:
http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-example-file-processing

But I like to use an XML file as input and write this to a MySQL-DB.
The XML-file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <Name>word</Name>
  <Surname>processor</Surname>
  <Phone>12333</Phone>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If i put this into my "in"-folder the file will be moved to the "out"-folder, but nothing is written into the database. There is no error message.

My Proxy-Service:

```
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="FileProxy" transports="vfs" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <clone>
            <target sequence="fileWriteSequence"/>
            <target sequence="databaseSequence"/>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">C:/wso2esb/testordner/out</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">C:/wso2esb/testordner/in</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">C:/wso2esb/testordner/error</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

And my Sequence:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="databaseSequence"
          trace="enable"
          statistics="enable">
   <log level="full">
      <property name="sequence" value="before-smooks"/>
   </log>
   <smooks config-key="smooks">
      <input type="xml"/>
      <output type="xml"/>
   </smooks>
   <log level="full">
      <property name="sequence" value="after-smooks"/>
   </log>
   <log level="full">
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                name="name"
                expression="//csv-record/name/text()"/>
      <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                name="surname"
                expression="//csv-record/surname/text()"/>
      <property name="phone" value="//csv-record/phone/text()"/>
   </log>
   <iterate xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
            xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
            xmlns:sec="http://secservice.samples.esb.wso2.org"
            expression="//csv-set/csv-record">
      <target>
         <sequence>
            <log level="full">
               <property name="State" value="Iteration"/>
            </log>
            <log level="full" category="DEBUG"/>
            <dbreport>
               <connection>
                  <pool>
                     <password>passwort</password>
                     <user>esb</user>
                     <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/</url>
                     <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                  </pool>
               </connection>
               <statement>
                  <sql>insert into info.info (name, surname, phone) values (?, ?, ?)</sql>
                  <parameter expression="//csv-record/name/text()" type="VARCHAR"/>
                  <parameter expression="//csv-record/surname/text()" type="VARCHAR"/>
                  <parameter expression="//csv-record/phone/text()" type="VARCHAR"/>
               </statement>
            </dbreport>
         </sequence>
      </target>
   </iterate>
   <log level="full" category="DEBUG"/>
</sequence>
```

I thought this would be a simple problem, but I'm not able to get it...
Like I said, it's working with a normal text-file, but not with XML. I tried different thinks and have no idea what else I could try...
Does someone know what's my mistake?

Update:

The log from the console:

```
[2013-04-12 09:35:55,687]  INFO - DBReportMediator Successfully created data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/.
[2013-04-12 09:36:10,170]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:
2CBD1753113A1373101365752170177, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope x
mlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
  <Name>word</Name>
  <Surname>processor</Surname>
  <Phone>12333</Phone>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2013-04-12 09:36:10,175]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:
a9252cd8-fe73-4e85-9f41-0842872d3a73, Direction: request, sequence = before-smooks, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encodi
ng='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
  <Name>word</Name>
  <Surname>processor</Surname>
  <Phone>12333</Phone>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2013-04-12 09:36:10,178]  INFO - LogMediator sequence = fileWriteSequence
[2013-04-12 09:36:10,246]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:
a9252cd8-fe73-4e85-9f41-0842872d3a73, Direction: request, sequence = after-smooks, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encodin
g='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><csv-set/></soapenv
:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2013-04-12 09:36:10,249]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:
a9252cd8-fe73-4e85-9f41-0842872d3a73, Direction: request, name = , surname = , phone = //csv-record/phone/text(), Envelo
pe: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s
oapenv:Body><csv-set/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2013-04-12 09:36:11,254]  WARN - TimeoutHandler Expiring message ID : urn:uuid:4c422f4e-aed5-4eaa-ad9b-e5407db20562; dr
opping message after global timeout of : 120 seconds
```

The fileWriteSequence looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="fileWriteSequence"
          trace="enable"
          statistics="enable">
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="sequence" value="fileWriteSequence"/>
   </log>
   <property xmlns:ns2="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
             expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.xml')"
             scope="transport"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   <send>
      <endpoint name="FileEpr">
         <address uri="vfs:C:/wso2esb/testordner/out"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

Smooks config:

```
<smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.0.xsd">

  <!--Configure the CSVParser to parse the message into a stream of SAX events. -->
  <resource-config selector="org.xml.sax.driver">
    <resource>org.milyn.csv.CSVParser</resource>
    <param name="fields" type="string-list">name,surname,phone</param>
  </resource-config>

</smooks-resource-list>
```

I also changed the code of the databaseSequence above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy service looks ok. But I have few concerns.

1. Why have you put the sql query as CDATA. Please see the sample available [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/DBReport+Mediator).
2. You have not mentioned the database name in the connection url. May be it is not a problem since you have used the database.table format in your sql query.
3. After fixing and 1 and 2, if the issue still exists, try your proxy with only one sequence. i.e. Avoid the file write sequence temporarily and try only with the dbwrite sequence.

You can also log the entries which you are going to insert before the DBReport mediator. i.e. Right after the smooks mediator, put a log mediator and log the name, surname and phone. This will make sure you are trying to insert values which are correctly extracted from the message.

Comment: I tried this. The sql query was put as CDATA by the esb, I only wrote the statement in the design view. For the database I used the database.table format like you expected. I also tried to use only one sequence and to change the order of the sequences. But nothing helps. I will add some code in my question. In the databaseSequence I added a log mediator, but I'm not sure if it is correct. Maybe the problem is the smooks mediator?

Comment: Yes. Seems like the problem is with smooks configs. Log entries you have put after the smooks mediator prints an empty csv-set. I think the problem is, you are providing a xml file as the input, but you have configured the smooks in a way which it expects a csv file. You will have to search on how to configure smooks to be used with a xml input file.